# Why does STDOUT only show the message from one return in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, lambda, return

I am new to using Ruby. I have been learning through RubyMonk.

I came across this example code:

```
def a_method
 lambda { return "we just returned from the block" }.call
 return "we just returned from the calling method"
end

puts a_method
```

The message produced by STDOUT is "we  just returned from the calling method". However, if I delete `return "we just returned from the calling method"`
from the code, the message is "we just returned from the block".

Why is it that both messages are not produced with the original code? Is this a RubyMonk thing or is it always like this?

Answer (score 4):

The only output is done by `puts a_method`, so only the return value of `a_method`, which is `"we just returned from the calling method"` is seen in the output.

---

If the `return` line were removed, then `a_method` becomes:

```
def a_method
  lambda { return "we just returned from the block" }.call
end
```

Since no explicte `return` statement is available, the return value of `a_method` is its last expression, which is the return value of the lambda, i.e, `"we just returned from the block"`.

---

How to make both strings seen? Try this:

```
def a_method
  puts lambda { return "we just returned from the block" }.call
  return "we just returned from the calling method"
end

puts a_method
```

By `puts` the return value of the lambda, `"we just returned from the block"` is also there in the output.

Answer (score 1):

It's because in first case, you swallow the result of your lambda call. You return only `"we just returned from the calling method"` string, which is put on STDOUT.